# How to return values from javascript library to android/iOS native code

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, flutter

I'd like to use a javascript library in flutter app. The library is not supposed to invoke any UI, only receive parameters and return textual outputs.

The easiest way would be to use a native plugin to call React. However all integration guides and posts I found explain either how to use react to generate UI modules, or how to return output from native code to react (using promises), not how to return its outputs to the native code.

The solution could be to either catch console.log output or some asynchronous callback, but I couldn't find any such solution.

I also tried mobile node.js by janea systems, but that I also couldn't get it to return value from the javascript code.

Thanks for any pointers. If some will help me, I'll make sure to put the sample code here.

Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Flutter doesn't provide a way to run JavaScript directly.

You can use a WebView plugin like https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/webview_flutter to execute JavaScript.